# Simple way of getting a file with ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, filenames

Is there a way of getting a filename without having to upload information to a database using ajax?

I basically want to click on an html element, trigger a jquery function, and run php code to read a directory.

I know I can upload the filenames to a DB, then just pull the info off it with ajax, but it's a really small project and I'd like to not use a database.

Comment: AJAX doesn't care where the data comes from, that's entirely up to the PHP script. It can access a database, read a file, read a directory, whatever.

Comment: yea his right ,definitely you should take a read of php file handling functions..

Comment: Ok cool, so just make a regular ajax function and pull the filename with opendir, etc. ?

Comment: @JoseF did you even try it before you came to ask?

Comment: @Barmar: Actually, [SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) states that the host, port, and hostname, must be the same server you are running the scripts from.

Comment: @DaveChen I don't see how that's relevant. His AJAX will be calling his own PHP scripts, which should be in his domain. My point was that the PHP scripts can do anything, they're not limited to database access.

Comment: `where the data` can be confused with anywhere.

Comment: @DaveChen OK, AJAX doesn't care where your PHP script gets its data from.

Comment: yeah @Barmar is right, what matters is what you put on your php script that you trigerred.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX doesnt care where you get you data. Because its just run the PHP script you are directing through when your ajax is triggered.To make it short what matters is the script you write to run when ajax trigerred it.

[BASIC PHP FILE HANDLING](http://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete)